# IE8/9 table-header-group support?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

According to the various compatibility documents around, IE8/9 is meant to support **display: table-header-group**, but it doesn't appear to do so.

If you view [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vogomatix/z82ktxer/2/) in IE8/9 (using a VM or using IE8/9 compatibility in later versions) - the footer moves back to the bottom, implying it is ignoring the table-header-group styling. Various sites indicate this should be supported in IE8 onwards, so what gives? Are the various sites incorrect, or have I made an error?

```
<head lang="en">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Foot 1</th>
            <th>Foot 2</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>1.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

**Update:** retested in a IE8 VM instead of using IE10/11 browser/document modes, problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The sites do claim that IE 8 supports 'table-header-group', but they are only partially right.  If the target element is 'div', instead of 'tfoot', IE 8 treats the 'div' as a 'thead' and moves it above the 'tbody' element.

But, if the target element is 'tfoot', then IE 8 ignores the CSS and displays the element below the 'tbody' element.

I've tried it in Chrome, and Chrome moves 'tfoot' above 'tbody'.

I haven't tried it with other elements or browsers.

So, short version is that you haven't made a mistake, but the sites have not given complete information regarding its behavior in IE8.